# Limit users to only access their profiles using Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise, authorization

I have currently set my app so that on successful sign in the app redirects the user to their profile at `localhost:3000/users/id` however if I am the first user `id => 1` and type `users/2` I have full access to this profile.  I have been trying to find how to stop this using devise.  I'm pretty new to rails so I'm sure I'm missing something simple, I have used the `before_filter :authenticate_user!` but this is obviously just checking if a user is signed in, but doesn't limit access to other users' profiles.  I have read a bit on CanCan but this seems a bit overkill for what I am trying to achieve.  Any pointers much appreciated.

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  before_filter :user_authorization

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def show

    @user = User.find(current_user[:id])

  end


  private

     def user_authorization
        redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.id == params[:id]
     end
end
```

This is being reported from the server:

```
Started GET "/users/2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-06-24 13:00:38 +0200
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"2"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 2 LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Filter chain halted as :user_authorization rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 20ms (ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)
```

Comment: use current_user method. see the doc

Answer (score 3):

In your controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :validate_user, :only => :show

  def show
     @user = User.find(params[:id]
  end


  def validate_user
    redirect_to courses_path unless current_user.id.to_s == params[:id]
  end

end
```

Notice the `current_user.id.to_s` since current_user.id is an integer and params[:id] is a string.

Answer (score 2):

In general, I'd say there are two approaches to solving this kind of problem:

1. Rolling your own code and implementing checks in your controllers (or potentially in your model classes), and
2. using a gem that enforces rules for you.

If you want to role-your-own, the simplest way would be to simply put checks in your controller that makes sure they get redirected if they try to look at a profile that isn't theirs. One way to do this using a before filter is this, though you'd want to adapt it for the behavior that makes sense for your app.

```
  before_filter :validate_user
  def validate_user
    redirect_to home_path unless current_user and current_user.id == params[:id]
  end
```

If you want to use a gem, then I'd recommend cancan as you've mentioned or another gem called Acts as Tenant. I've seen it used for similar things. But if all you want is to lock down the user profile, adding code to the controller probably works fine.

Answer (score 1):

And voilà:

```
  before_filter :user_authorization

  private

     def user_authorization
        redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.id == params[:id]
     end
```

current_user is an helper that contains current logged user.

Comment: Thanks but this isn't working I've tried it in the users_controller and the application_controller, neither stopped me viewing other profiles?

Comment: Thanks but this just seems to redirect back to the root path for all `/users/id` now.  I've added my code above to see if I have something set wrong.